# PDO exec retornando false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo um curso online sobre PHP com PDO e estou tendo problemas logo na primeira aula, com o código:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost, dbname = curso_php_oop', 'root', ''); //instanciando a classe do PDO, iniciando com parâmetros: 1º banco de dados, 2º usuário, 3º senha, 4º algumas opçoes
var_dump($pdo->exec('INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha) VALUES ("fulano", "silva", "fulano@hotmail.com", "123456");')); //exec: executa a query no banco e retorna a quantidade de linhas que foram afatadas pelo comando enviado
```

sempre que executo este comando recebo um bool(false)

Comment: Vejo que você é novo por aqui, aproveite e faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funciona o SOpt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para construir um objeto PDO você deve passar no primeiro argumento as opções de construção separadas por ponto-virgula.

No seu código você está separando as opções por virgula.

Tente construir o objeto da seguinte forma:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=curso_php_oop', 'root', '');
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, deu certo, não estou acreditando que o problema era eu utilizar espaçamentos para o meu código ficar mais bonitinho kkkk